# Java Null Conditional

Tags: java, refactoring

I have the following pattern appearing many times in my Java code and was wondering how some of you might refactor it.

```
Object obj1 = buildObj1();
if (obj1 != null) {
    return obj1;
}

Object obj2 = buildObj2();
if (obj2 != null) {
    return obj2;
}

Object obj3 = buildObj3();
if (obj3 != null) {
    return obj3;
}
```

Comment: What is the logic in the else case? throw an exception?

Comment: At the very bottom, it returns null.

Comment: Can you make buildObj(); always return an object?

Comment: @Allain - I just made a small correction to the code, assuming it looked incorrect. Feel free to revert it if I'm in the wrong. :)

Comment: Is the code above in one method, or you are just demonstrating the repetition.

Comment: the code above is in one method.

Answer (score 5):

Because Java doesn't have first-class functions, the best you could really do would be to have an interface for "building things", and then do something like this:

```
for (Builder<T> builder : builders) {
    T obj = builder.build();
    if (obj != null) return obj;
}
```

The Builder interface would just be something like:

```
public interface Builder<T> {
    T build();
}
```

`builders` in the top snippet is an `Iterable<Builder<T>>`.

Comment: I forgot to hit submit. This was my solution!

Comment: You may want to write some kind of management class to handle the builders, as well, if the exact order of methods is the same.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall - made me laugh.

Comment: Would you have these builders internal to the class, or would you promote it to a top level class?

Comment: The Builder interface is pretty generic, so I'd probably put that somewhere at the top level. Whether the implementations of that interface are top-level or not depends on how generally useful they are.

Actually, that Builder interface is very similar to the Supplier interface in Google Collections (http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html). You many want to take a look at how Supplier is used in Google Collections, and perhaps even consider using it.

Answer (score 2):

Is that code all called sequentially in the same method?  You could use a [Factory method](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) that would always return the correct object (either obj1, obj2, or obj3).  You could pull the "null or real object" conditional test from each `buildObj()` method into this factory method so that you always get a valid object from the new factory method.

---

Alternatively, if you just mean that you have the `if (obj != null)` tests everywhere you might instead consider using the Null Object Pattern:

> Instead of using a null reference to convey absence of an object (for instance, a non-existent customer), one uses an object which implements the expected interface, but whose method body is empty. The advantage of this approach over a working default implementation is that a Null Object is very predictable and has no side effects: it does nothing.